# NoClassDefFoundError after deploying WAR on Weblogic10.3.6 created from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I've created a simple web app and it works fine when I deploy it on internally configured server in eclipse.
But now I exported it as a WAR and tried to deploy on another Weblogic server. I get the following error:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ofss/UcbparamConnector
at jsp_servlet.__ucbparam12._jspService(__ucbparam12.java:88)**

The UcbparamConnector.class is present in the WAR under WEB-INF/classes/ but looks like it is not found during the runtime. Please suggest what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Is UcbparamConnector class placed inside WEB-INF/classes/com/ofss/ directory ?

Comment: Yes, I put it there on that path on server.

Answer (score 0):

The other Weblogic server was configured to run on different JRE which was causing this problem.
After changing JDK path, web app is working as expected.
Thank you.